# Knockout.js: wait for the ViewModel instantiation to complete

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want the viewmodel instantiation to complete and then only call `loadUniqueUrl(viewModel);` in the following code:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel(data, subTopicId, chapterId, planId);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
loadUniqueUrl(viewModel);
```

I can't modify the ViewModel.I don't know how to use callback in this case.Please help

Comment: Your code exectutes line by line, so loadUniqueUrl will be called, when applyBidings is finished. Of course if you don't have any ajax calls in your ViewModel.

Comment: not exactly @Alexander. Javascript is async.

Comment: you should be using callbacks

Comment: It's a little hidden in the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)(see note 4) and [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)(see note 7), but you can use `afterRender` to fire a function that occurs *after* rending the DOM. Or you could use a custom binding, which is a better solution and not that hard to do.

Comment: @om_deshpande could you elaborate what you mean by not exactly? AFAIK `ko.applyBindings` is a synchronous function and `loadUniqueUrl` will be called after that. You can be sure that everything will be set up, as long as there are no asynchronous binding handlers involved, or async calls in the view model, just like Alexander said.

Comment: @jeremija "as long as there are no asynchronous binding handlers involved, or async calls in the view model, just like Alexander said." - this is exactly what i mean. We don't know what's inside the constructor or the functions that the OP is calling. IMO it is always a good practice to structure code using callbacks. Otherwise, things can go  quickly go out of control as the code base grows.

Comment: Without knowing what is happening inside the viewmodel, there is insufficient information to know if it has completed or not. It should fire an event or call a callback, perhaps using a deferred to signal it is loaded.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is usually very little time needed for bindings to complete...in the case where things are just firing off too quickly for you and you have no control over your object model, wrap the function you want to perform in a simple setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(loadUniqueUrl(viewModel), 200)
```

Comment: Bit of a sledgehammer approach. If you complete faster, UI sits around waiting. If load takes longer than 200, then you start loading on a partially initialised object, which could lead to all sorts of issues.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive input and wise words. As he stated, he doesn't have access to the view model...if this also implies he doesn't have access to adding ko.computed objects, then the option to 'deferEvaluation' is not available. Good thing one of us was helpful.

Comment: I didn't offer an incomplete solution or get snarky because someone pointed out the potential problems with my solution either. Good thing one of us didn't take it personally.